# making a cross-platform environment.yml

Tags: python, conda

I have written a python application in Linux and I want to export the `environment.yml` file so that users can recreate the environment in either Linux or Windows. The command I run is:

```
conda env export --from-history > environment.yml
```

However a couple of the dependencies shown in this yml file are Linux-specific (not really surprising at all and they are both C/C++ compiler related). For example:

```
  - libgcc
  - gcc=12.1.0
```

Hence running `conda env create -n my_env -f environment.yml` from windows will fail.

I was just wondering what you guys typically do in these cases. Shall I go to my Windows computer, create a fresh `env`, install all the packages by hand one at a time and once I manage to run my code successfully create an `environment_win.yml` and distribute two `yml` files, one for windows and another for Linux?